# Web API approach

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm newbie in the Web API, I have read some documentation, but a little misunderstand about architecture. I.e. I need to create many get methods, for different entities. But I can have one and only one GET method without parameters. So, I have to create one more API controller, even if this controller will have only one method at all? What sense in this restriction?

Comment: Include the method name in the route, then use multiple methods.

Comment: @SLaks, thank you for your response. But what is background for this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think in terms of URLs/routes. If you wanted to access a Foo entity, you'd go to /api/foo, and if you wanted to access a Bar entity, you'd go to /api/bar.

Having said that, that's the convention, and you can break it if you want. You can definitely have more than one GET method in a controller. The action would just need to have a different route. You could set that up using attribute routing e.g.

```
public class FooBarController : ApiController
{
    [Route("foo")]
    public Foo Get() {...}

    [Route("bar")]
    public Bar GetBar() {...}
}
```

However, for different resources you'd generally want to stick to different controllers as it makes your code more maintainable - it allows for a clear correlation between models and controllers. There's nothing wrong with having many small controllers.

Comment: yes, but often it's necessary to have 2 get methods for getting 2 collections of Foo, just different conditions. It would be better to have one method, but different parameters?

Comment: You can definitely create more than one GET methods for different conditions in the same controller. They'll just have to receive those "conditions" as parameters in the Get() method. E.g. Get(string id).